# Clustering by Bag of Unique Words (Python/Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, text-mining

My goal is to **hard cluster a large number of unique users by bags of unique, key words** (each word only appears within each user's word list once) in Python. An example of the input format would be:

- Johnny - Dog Cat Bear
- Mark - Cat Apple Peach
- Lisa - Apple Peach Orange

Intuitively, if we selected 2 clusters we would expect Mark and Lisa to be clustered together ('Apple' and 'Peach' are 2 common key words, while Johnny and Lisa share no common words, as well as Johnny and Mark only sharing 1; 'Cat') and Johnny to be clustered by himself.

Getting more technical, I have tried a few approaches but I feel as though my current solution is not informed enough. I have vectorised KeyWords (by TF-IDF) and applied a simple K-Means analysis, which produced what seemed to be quite useful and intuitive results. However, I have the underlying feeling that TF-IDF is not relevant, as all of the words are already defining. I'd really appreciate any insights, observations or recommendations anyone has on standout issues or better approaches. I've put the example code below:

```
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.feature_extraction import text

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

data = [{'User': 'Johnny', 'KeyWords': 'Dog Cat Bear'},
    {'User': 'Mark', 'KeyWords': 'Cat Apple Peach'},
    {'User': 'Lisa', 'KeyWords': 'Apple Peach Orange'}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Optimal_k = 2

WordVectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')

X = WordVectorizer.fit_transform(df['KeyWords'])

model = KMeans(n_clusters=Optimal_k, init='k-means++', max_iter=200, n_init=10)

model.fit(X)

df['Cluster'] = pd.DataFrame(model.labels_)

df
```

This is a semi [cross-post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/27829/clustering-observations-by-string-sequences-python-pandas-df/27976?noredirect=1#comment32660_27976) from DataScience, where I received some interesting recommendations. I wanted to post here for a more practical analysis, and post in a basic format that others with similar issues can hopefully learn from. I've put more scenario specific information below.

**Specific Dataset Info** - 2 million observations/unique users, around 3500 unique possible words. ~70% of users only have 1 KeyWord (Median 1, mean 1.5), so my assumption is only to train the model on the remaining 30%.

**Analysed Models** - I've looked into K-Means (currently seems best regardless of lower robustness, K chosen by elbow method), LDA (soft cluster, results made little sense), Gaussian Mixtures (Dataset too large to convert TF-IDF vector to dense) and DBSCAN (selecting neighbour distance seems quite difficult with the given data). Note that I still only understand the basics of most, so it is likely that I may be overseeing many applications.

Comment: The IDF factor is used to normalize frequencies. If you don't care how frequent a term is, just a TF vector should suffice for your task. Basically, each bit in your vector corresponds to one unique entry in your lexicon. So in your toy example you could say 1 means Dog is present, 2 means Cat is present, 4 means Peach, 8 means Apple, etc. Now you can just do a boolean AND of two vectors and count the number of set bits.

Comment: That's a very good point. Layman's wise, do you think it would be fair to say that while IDF is effective for constraining non-key words, considering that all words in the lexicon are equally relevant IDF is obsolete?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "obsolete", just not relevant for your use case.  Of course, I was slightly imprecise before, as you also don't care about TF, just T -- if the frequency is zero, the term is absent.